# How to capture the mouse movement within a given window in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, window, mouse, pyautogui

I know how to capture mouse movement for the whole screen but I want to capture mouse movement in a specific window in python. I need to track the location of the mouse in that particular window.

Answer (score 0):

- 1. You need to create a window.

  - ```py
    cv2.namedWindow(winname='my_drawing', flags=cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    ```
  - Optional: If you want, you can resize the window:

    - ```py
      cv2.resizeWindow(winname='my_drawing', width=600, height=600)
      ```
- 2. You need a mouse `callback` function which will return the mouse coordinates. Assume I want to draw rectangles on the screen.

  - ```py
    cv2.setMouseCallback('my_drawing', draw_rectangle)
    ```
  - My `draw_rectangle` will be:
  - ```py
    def draw_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):
        global x_mouse, y_mouse
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=(x, y), 
                          pt2=(x+10, y+10), 
                          color=(180, 105, 255),
                          thickness=4)
        cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        x_mouse, y_mouse = x, y
    ```
  - We have two `global` variables, which we will declare outside of the function as

    - ```py
      x_mouse, y_mouse = (None, None)
      ```
- 3. Since I'm planning to draw a rectangle on an image. I should be declaring an RGB image with the same size as `my_drawing` named window.

  - ```py
    img = np.zeros((600, 600, 3), np.uint8)
    ```
  - Below part is optional, I want to display coordinates when I press `s` keyword.

    ```py
    while True:
        cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
        elif k == ord('s'):
            print("x, y = ({}, {})".format(x_mouse, y_mouse))
    ```

So when I click one time on the screen and 2 times on `s` keyword result will be:

[image]

```py
x, y = (503, 420)
x, y = (363, 362)
x, y = (499, 274)
x, y = (289, 291)
x, y = (304, 439)
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

x_mouse, y_mouse = (None, None)


def draw_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global x_mouse, y_mouse
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=(x, y),
                      pt2=(x+10, y+10),
                      color=(180, 105, 255),
                      thickness=4)
        cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        x_mouse, y_mouse = x, y


cv2.namedWindow(winname='my_drawing', flags=cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(winname='my_drawing', width=600, height=600)
cv2.setMouseCallback('my_drawing', draw_rectangle)
img = np.zeros((600, 600, 3), np.uint8)
while True:
    cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        print("x, y = ({}, {})".format(x_mouse, y_mouse))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```